# Should we call it DocumentDb or CosmosDB SQL Api

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm little bit confused with the naming.

First of all, is there any difference between Document DB and Cosmos DB Sql Api, or it is just another name?

Second, in order to access Cosmos DB Sql Api I have to use DocumentDB nuget package. Will it be ever renamed or DocumentDB naming stays relevant.

Third, in my code, when naming my classes, should I use DocumentDB, or CosmodDbSqlApi? E.g. `DocumentDbStore`, or `CosmodDbSqlApiStore`, etc...

Comment: SQL API (which now shows up in the portal as `"Core (SQL)"` ) = original DocumentDB API. I'd suggest posting to UserVoice if you have a suggestion for the name. Unfortunately, debating the name here is off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DocumentDB has been rebranded to Cosmos DB and everything new related to it will be named Cosmos DB.

Some SDKs kept the old name for backwards compatibility sake but it should not be referenced as DocumentDB but rather Cosmos DB. `CosmosDbStore` the most appropriate way to name your class (at least in my opinion).

Comment: This should really be a comment, not an answer. Also, I realize this is a bit pedantic, but the branding is actually "Cosmos DB" (with a space).

Comment: @DavidMakogon Thanks for the clarification. The space won't fly on a property or field name so I'm leaving that as it is. About the comment thing, I actually answered his question about the naming so I don't see why it should be a comment. I might be missing something though.

Comment: Right - spaces won't work within variable names. Merely pointing out that the brand has a space (which has been brought up in the past by the product team). The original question is (in my opinion) off-topic, as the idea of what to name something is fairly broad and opinion-based.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I agree, naming is largely opinion-based, but i thought it wouldn't be fair to flag it because his question is focused on the product's naming and not general method naming.